# How to make React Suspense component conditional when SSR?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-suspense

I want to pass a flag prop to Suspense component, telling it to behave like a normal div, hence being loaded immediately when `renderToPipeableStream` on the server.

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

function ConditionalSuspense(): React.ReactElement {
  return (
    <Suspense enabled={false}>
      <div>
        <div>When enabled is false, this will be loaded sync on server</div>
        <Suspense>This will be loaded async on client, because by default suspense is enabled</Suspense>
      </div>
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

On the server I will have

```
import { renderToPipeableStream } from 'react-dom/server';
import { ConditionalSuspense } from './ui';

const stream = renderToPipeableStream(ConditionalSuspense, ...);
```

Comment: What about something like `let ConditionalSuspense = enabled ? Suspense : 'div'` then instead of `<Suspense />` it will be `<ConditionalSuspense />`.

Comment: oh my it is that simple yes! Thank you.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I'm getting the error `Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`